# Meditation in Ramcharitramanas

Tags: vedanta, ramcharitmanas

Is there any meditation prescribed in Ramcharitramanas ? lIKE Meditating on Brahman or Brahman etc

Thanks

Comment: You've already posted this here, though: [Meditation in Ramcharitramanas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/56816/meditation-in-ramcharitramanas)

Comment: Ramcharitramanas was written by Tulsidas. He had a doctrine that particularly during that age, Japa is more effective than meditation. I highly doubt if that'd be the case. In actual Ramayana, it is possible of any mention of meditation to be present, but not particularly here.